# Evaluate large Fibonacci numbers

Tags: integer-sequence

I want to evaluate that `Fibonacci[28143753246]`.
However the result is `OverFlow[]`. Is there any way to evaluate it?

Thank you.

Comment: See [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/133618/extreme-fibonacci) on PPCG, especially [this Mathematica answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/133693/65836). While this question was about the one billionth Fibonacci number and your question is about the 28-billionth Fibonacci number, you may gain some ideas.

Answer (score 11):

Have you thought about whether this is a reasonable thing to try to compute exactly?

[There is a closed form formula for Fibonacci numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Closed-form_expression) which allows us to estimate the number of digits in the answer:

```
Fibonacci[k] // FunctionExpand
(* ((1/2 (1 + Sqrt[5]))^k - (2/(1 + Sqrt[5]))^k Cos[k π])/Sqrt[5] *)
```

For large `k` the answer is approximately

```
GoldenRatio^k / Sqrt[5]
```

therefore it will have about

```
k / (Log[10]/Log[GoldenRatio])
```

decimal digits, or

```
k / (Log[2]/Log[GoldenRatio])
```

binary digits.

Plugging in your value gives about $10^{10}$ binary digits. That is on the order of gigabytes of data, *just to store the final result*, not to mention computing it to the desired accuracy, and storing intermediate results.

To me, this suggests that:

- This is not a particularly useful thing to compute *exactly* except for a very few very special uses
- Computing it exactly requires a lot of resources, and probably an efficient custom approach (instead of a general system like Mathematica)
- You can get an *approximate* result using the formula above

Could Mathematica do the exact computation in principle? I do not know how `Fibonacci` works, but Mathematica has a limit on the largest numbers it can handle.  This differs from computer to computer and can be checked using

```
$MaxNumber
(* 1.605216761933662*10^1355718576299609 *)
```

As you can see, on my computer this limit is much higher than the result you are looking for, so in principle, Mathematica can store *the final result* (but perhaps not the intermediate ones).  Any time `$MaxNumber` is exceeded, the result will be `Overflow[]`.

I tried to evaluate your input, and after letting it run for 5 minutes I cancelled the evaluation. During this time it did not throw an `Overflow[]`, but I do not know how long the computation would take.

What about the approximate result?  That is easy:

```
N[GoldenRatio^28143753246/Sqrt[5]]
(* 2.040489385525467*10^5881696578 *)
```

Comment: Thanks for your responce. However, the result of the code `N[GoldenRatio^28143753246/Sqrt[5]]` is also `OverFlow[]` in my computer.

Comment: @MATIRMAK Are you using a very old 32-bit version? What does `{$Version, $ReleaseNumber, $SystemWordLength}` say?

Comment: My computer says `Version`is 8.0 and 64 bit, `Releasenumber` is 0 and `SystemWordLenght`is 64. Since i am not expert of the using Mathematica well, i did not unberstand what are they.

Comment: @MATIRMAK I suspect it may be a limitation of version 8 then. Probably `$MaxNumber` is too low in that version, even in 64-bit. Version 10.0 can handle it, I have not tried 9.0. You could try to the free online version of Mathematica (which is at version 11.1). It has a time limit, but it should be able to do `N[GoldenRatio^28143753246/Sqrt[5]]` (which is instantaneous).

Comment: ``Fibonacci[28143753246`100]`` could also be used to get the approximate result.